# What is the way to read tables displayed after commands in bash

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

Is there is the best way to read results of some bash commands, which are displayed as a table, if I need some particular row and column there?
For example, when I run this line:

```
gcloud app instances describe $instance_name --service=postprocessing --version=$instance_version
```

I get this:

```
startTime: '2020-08-03T16:29:29.142Z'
vmDebugEnabled: true
vmIp: xx.xx.xxx.xxx
vmStatus: RUNNING
```

I need only IP from this table, how do I get it?
I found only one way, to save the whole output as an array and then get -3rd element of it. I was wondering if there is a better way to it?
Also for other types of output with more "columns" which have a header, like this one:

```
mst@cloudshell:~ (me)$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1995         469         279           0        1247        1379
Swap:           767           0         767
```

How do I get free/Swap, for example?

Comment: `gcloud .... | sed -n 's/^vmIp:[[:blank:]]*//p'`

Comment: this works but why not just filter results using the api since you're passing $instance_name - e.g. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/list Additionally why not use json output and just jq it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `awk` to get the value you want in the output.

To set $VMIP variable with the `vmIP` value (2nd field):

```
VMIP=$(gcloud app ... | awk '/vmIp:/ {print $2}' )
```

To set $SWAP_FREE variable with the `Swap free` value (4th field):

```
SWAP_FREE=$(free -m | awk '/Swap:/ {print $4}')
```